# Calculate begin and end position of a word in a document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text-processing

I have a text document represented as an `array` of sentences and for each sentence I have an `array` of word tokens.

I have to calculate the absolute begin and the end of the token position in the document for each token position, hence if in a sentence I have `ipsum` five times, I must get the right position in that sentence for each occurrence.

I wrote this function

```
// calculate begin and end to each token in a sentence
function calculateTokenBeginEnd(textArray) {
  var currentText = [];
  textArray.sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence.tokens.length; ++i) {
      var token = sentence.tokens[i];
      var word = token.word;
      if (i > 0) {
        var thisBegin = token.characterOffsetBegin;
        var previousEnd = sentence.tokens[i - 1].characterOffsetEnd;
        if (thisBegin > previousEnd) {
          currentText.push(' ');
        }
      }
      token.characterOffsetBegin = currentText.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < word.length; ++j) {
        currentText.push(word[j]);
      }
      token.characterOffsetEnd = currentText.length;
    }
    currentText.push('\n');
  });
  return textArray;
} //calculateTokenBeginEnd
```

but there is something wrong. The calculated `characterOffsetBegin` and `characterOffsetEnd` are wrong.
A document has the following structure

```
{
    "sentences": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
          "tokens": [
            {
              "index": 1,
              "word": "Lorem",
              "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
              "characterOffsetEnd": 5
            },
            {
              "index": 2,
              "word": "ipsum",
              "characterOffsetBegin": 5,
              "characterOffsetEnd": 10
            },
    ...
          ]
        },
        {
          "index": 1,
          "text": " consectetur adipiscing elit,",
          "tokens": [
            {
              "index": 1,
              "word": "",
              "characterOffsetBegin": 24,
              "characterOffsetEnd": 24
            },
    ...
    }
```

This is an example using this method. Then `calculateTokenBeginEnd` should then calculate the token begin and end indexes, while the `text2SentencesTokens` created the document structure above. The `calculateTokenBeginEnd` does not work as expected.

```js
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n consectetur adipiscing elit,\nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\nut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim ad minim veniam,\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi\nut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet etwas,\nsunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"

// to map a text to sentences and tokens
text2SentencesTokens = function(text) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    let sentences = text.split(/\n+/g);
    let sentencesP = sentences.map((sentence, lineIndex) => { // for each sentence
      return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        let tokens = sentence.split(/\s+/g);
        let tokensP = tokens.map((token, tokenIndex) => { // for each token
          let item = {
            "index": (tokenIndex + 1),
            "word": token
          }
          if (typeof(tokenP) == 'function') {
            return tokenP.apply(self, [item]);
          } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
              resolve(item);
            });
          }
        });
        Promise.all(tokensP)
          .then(res => {
            resolve({
              index: lineIndex,
              text: sentence,
              tokens: res
            });
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      });
    });
    Promise.all(sentencesP)
      .then(res => {
        resolve({
          sentences: res
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  });
} //text2SentencesTokens

// calculate begin and end to each token in a sentence
function calculateTokenBeginEnd(textArray) {
  var currentText = [];
  textArray.sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence.tokens.length; ++i) {
      var token = sentence.tokens[i];
      var word = token.word;
      if (i > 0) {
        var thisBegin = token.characterOffsetBegin;
        var previousEnd = sentence.tokens[i - 1].characterOffsetEnd;
        if (thisBegin > previousEnd) {
          currentText.push(' ');
        }
      }
      token.characterOffsetBegin = currentText.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < word.length; ++j) {
        currentText.push(word[j]);
      }
      token.characterOffsetEnd = currentText.length;
    }
    currentText.push('\n');
  });
  return textArray;
} //calculateTokenBeginEnd

text2SentencesTokens(text)
  .then(sentences => {
    sentences = calculateTokenBeginEnd(sentences);
    console.log(sentences);

  })
```

**[UPDATE]**

According to the suggestion I rewrote the function as follows:

```
   function calculateTokenBeginEnd(textArray) {
        var wordStart=-1;
        for (var j = 0; j < textArray.sentences.length; ++j) {
            var sentence=textArray.sentences[j];
            wordStart +=1;
            for (var i = 0; i < sentence.tokens.length; ++i) {
                var token = sentence.tokens[i];
                var word = token.word;
                var wordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(" + word + ")\\b", "gi");
                var match = wordRegex.exec(sentence.text);
                var previousEnd = 0;
                wordStart += match.index + previousEnd;
                var wordEnd = wordStart + word.length - 1;
                token.characterOffsetBegin = wordStart;
                token.characterOffsetEnd = wordEnd;
            }
        }
    }//calculateTokenBeginEnd
```

Any better solution to that?

**[UPDATE 2]**
I have updated the `text2SentencesTokens` according to the proposed solution. The problem is that this solution will not work properly when there are multiple matches of the same `token` in one or more sentences, because it will overwrite the start and end positions with the last matched position, so the token `down` here will get the last matched positions:

```
   {
      "index": 2,
      "word": "down",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 70,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 73
    }
```

in the first occurrence of the first sentence, while it should have had the first matched position.

```js
// convert a text document into a sentences array and a token array for each sentence
function text2SentencesTokens(text, tokenP) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    let sentences = text.split(/\n+/g);
    let sentencesP = sentences.map((sentence, lineIndex) => { // for each sentence
      return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        let tokens = sentence.replace(/[\\+;:\?!\»\«\>\<\]\[\)\(,\.\‘'“”"]/g, '').split(/\s+/g);
        let tokensP = tokens.map((token, tokenIndex) => { // for each token
          let item = {
            "index": (tokenIndex + 1),
            "word": token
          }
          var escaped = token.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
          var wordRegex = RegExp("\\b(" + escaped + ")\\b", "g");
          var match = null;
          while ((match = wordRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
            var wordStart = match.index;
            var wordEnd = wordStart + token.length - 1;
            item.characterOffsetBegin = wordStart;
            item.characterOffsetEnd = wordEnd;
          }

          if (typeof(tokenP) == 'function') {
            return tokenP.apply(self, [item, sentence]);
          } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
              resolve(item);
            });
          }
        });
        Promise.all(tokensP)
          .then(res => {
            resolve({
              index: lineIndex,
              text: sentence,
              tokens: res
            });
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      });
    });
    Promise.all(sentencesP)
      .then(res => {
        resolve({
          sentences: res
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  });
} //text2SentencesTokens

text = "Steve down walks warily down the street down\nWith the brim pulled way down low";
text2SentencesTokens(text)
  .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an easier way to calculate the start/end of a word in a sentence, hopefully it will help

```js
var word = "Lorem";
var reg = RegExp(word, 'g');
var sentence = "Lore ipsum Lorem dolor sit Lorem amet,";
var match;

console.log(sentence);
console.log(word);

while ((match = reg.exec(sentence)) !== null) {
  var wordStart = match.index;
  var wordEnd = wordStart + word.length - 1;
  console.log(wordStart + ' -start index');
  console.log(word.length + ' -length of word');
  console.log(wordEnd + ' -last character index, need to +1 to use with substring');
  console.log(sentence.substring(wordStart, wordEnd + 1) + '-using substring with calculated to find the word and verify');
}
```

Comment: thanks this suggestion helped to rewrote the question adding a possibile solution.

Comment: Also there is a problem with the `RegExp` that is we should take in account multiple matches of a `token` within the current `sentence`.

Comment: updated code to take into consideration for multiple matches.

Comment: hey @xtothel I have updated the question with your solution. The problem is that when cycling on tokens in a sentence, only the last match will be taken in account, so the matched position will be wrong.